# CakePhp4 - How to assert a count of executed queries in a Phpunit TestCase?

Tags: cakephp, phpunit, cakephp-4.x

In a TestCase I would like to Assert a count of executed queries. Should I use DebugKit or ConnectionManager ? I found some answer for older CakePhp but none for CakePhp 4.x.

Have you got some receipt ?

Thanks & cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set a dedicated logger.

```php
    $cm = ConnectionManager::get('default');
    $oldLogger = $cm->getLogger();
    $cm->setLogger( new class implements \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface {
        use \Psr\Log\LoggerTrait ;
        public $count = 0 ;
        public function log($level, $message, array $context = array()){
            $this->count ++ ;
            //echo "\n", $level,' ',$message, "\n";
        }
    });
    // Do some queries ...
    // Print the count
    echo 'Count: ', $cm->getLogger()->count, "\n" ;
    // And don't forget to restore the initial logger.
    $cm->setLogger( $oldLogger );
```

You can create a dedicated class from this code, with more options :-)